# Is it normal that void pointers give warnings?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm doing a school project and i'm going out of my away to get a better grade
With that being said i'm trying to use void pointers and type casting to make my program as general as possible for any type of scenario i throw at it.

I did some code and it does everything it should do but it gives me some warnings whenever i rebuild all but no warning when i compile it.

Side note: I know i am returning an integer to a pointer, but i can't return an local pointer otherwise it will not give me the result i need.

```
#define VERDADEIRO 1
#define FALSO 0
void * removido(info* tab,int pos)
{
    if(strcmp(tab[pos].nome,REMOVIDO) != 0)
    {
    return FALSO;
    }
    else
    {
    return VERDADEIRO;
    }
}
void * vazio(info* tab,int pos)
{
    if(strcmp(tab[pos].nome,CHAVENULA)!= 0)
    {
    return FALSO;
    }
    else
    {
        return VERDADEIRO;
    }
}

int listar(info * tab)
{
int i,c=0,j;

for(i=0;i<HASHTAM;i++)
{
    if((int *)removido(tab,i) ==FALSO && (int *)vazio(tab,i)==FALSO)
    {
    printf("Nome: %s",tab[i].nome);
    printf("NIF: %d\n",tab[i].NIF);
    printf("Morada: %s",tab[i].morada);
    printf("Telefone: %d\n",tab[i].telefone);
    printf("Codigo Postal: %d - %d\n",tab[i].codigopostal/1000,tab[i].codigopostal%1000);
    printf("Data de nasicmento: %d - %d - %d\n",tab[i].datanascimento%100,(tab[i].datanascimento%10000)/100,tab[i].datanascimento/10000);
    printf("Associado: %s\n",tab[i].infoassociado.associado);
    if(associado(tab,i)==VERDADEIRO)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            printf("Cota de %d anos atras - Estado: %c\n",j+1,tab[i].infoassociado.cotas[j]);
        }
    }
    c++;
    }
}
```

The warnings are comparison between pointer and integer and return makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: Using `void*` everywhere doesn't make your code as "generic as possible". Especially if the function is meant to return true or false, it makes it harder to follow. I'd deduct from your grade, for not using a bool type, if I was your teacher.

Comment: Neither of the functions you've declared need to be of type `void *`, because they clearly return a specific type. Your attempt to make it *as general as possible* is misguided. *Let's make this code as unclear as possible, because then I can say it's "generic"* isn't useful.

Comment: Well, my teacher was showing a presentation of a program from last year where a student of his created a program with all`void*` and he went crazy about it and was saying that was the best program he ever laid his hands on, i do understand i can do this easily using a bool return.

Comment: There may be some context from the presentation you missed, or maybe you just have a bad teacher :-)

Comment: There are three options here. (1) You didn't understand what about the use of `void*` impressed your teacher. (2) Your teacher was showing something for the sake of curiosity alone. (3) You have a bad teacher.

Comment: Using `void *` everywhere will not make your program more general, but will make you getting fired from a job more quickly. If that's what your teacher supports, he should get fired, too. That is bad and dangerous coding malstyle. Does he hate his compiler for inhibit type-checking?

Comment: `void * vazio(info* tab,int pos) { ...   return VERDADEIRO;` is undefined behavior (UB).

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not normal. They're telling you that you're using pointers incorrectly. `FALSO` and `VERDADEIRO` are not pointers.

Functions which return true and false are not a good use of void pointers, or pointers in general. Nor do you have to define your own true and false values. Instead use the booleans `true` and `false` from [stdbool.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h). (Note: this was added in C99 and some professors cling to the C90 standard.)

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool removido(info* tab,int pos)
{
    if(strcmp(tab[pos].nome,REMOVIDO) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool vazio(info* tab,int pos)
{
    if(strcmp(tab[pos].nome,CHAVENULA)!= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then later you can simply check whether the return value is true or false using normal boolean checks.

```
if( !removido(tab,i) && !vazio(tab,i) ) {
   ...
}
```

---

Note that double negatives make code difficult to understand. If you check for equality and return true, that is simpler.

```
bool vazio(info* tab,int pos)
{
    if(strcmp(tab[pos].nome,CHAVENULA)== 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To really simplify the code, you can take advantage that `strcmp(...) == 0` returns a boolean (technically it returns 0 or 1 which can be used as a boolean) and reduce those functions to one line.

```
bool removido(info* tab,int pos)
{
    return strcmp(tab[pos].nome,REMOVIDO) == 0;
}
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to say, but our teacher wants us to create this in order to be as usable with different "business" as possible, like, i just change some things, not everything on Types.c, and my hash.c just takes it and everything works just fine, it's kinda dumb since this is only a school project, but i do not make the rules ...

Comment: @PeSousa - We use `void*` when we cannot hard code a type, such as when writing a map that holds whatever. Returning a boolean value **is not** a case for not hard-coding the type.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you so much

Comment: @PeSousa There are some types which should be made generic so as not to limit what can be stored, like whether your hash works with strings or numbers or structs. That's an appropriate use of `void *`. That lets the caller worry about the type of the thing being stored (they'll also need to pass in function pointers about how to work with the data). There are other types which will not change because they are fundamental to how the function works. A function which returns true or false will always be `int` or `bool`. The number of buckets in your hash will always be an `int` or `size_t`.

Comment: Why not just `return !strcmp(tab[pos].nome,REMOVIDO)` in `removido` etc.?

Comment: @Olaf Because strcmp doesn't return a boolean. The function appears to be using strcmp for string equality. Returning the result of strcmp would add extra load on the caller, leak details about how it's implemented, and add the potential for a very easy mistake; the function would turn false when the result is true.

Comment: @Schwern: Try `bool b = 5;` and check the value! There is a standard conversion to bool according to what a conditional statement would do. Also, I added `!`, as the result has to be negated (it would not be necessary otherwise). It would not change the interface of the function (how would it, as a `_Bool` can only represent `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Olaf With the ! it's fine (sorry if I missed it, I'm on a phone). I have a slight preference to doing explicit comparisons for functions which return explicit values, but it's 6 of one, 0110 the other.

Comment: @Schwern: With `!` the comparison **is** explicit (although It prefer to use the language's well defined features). Before C99, `!!` was ideomatic to enforce `0`/`1` without negation. I'm very sure compilers hrecognise this and don't emit more code than necessary. Not sure about the conditional statement otoh.